# Selenium webdriver : Not able to perform Keyboard actions like obj.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "m")); in Google Chrome

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, cucumber-junit

On a web page i have execute SHIFT+m from my keyboard for which i have used Action class but that step getting skipped every time in my code and the execution went to the next step.

Tried with both Action class and Robot class in Cucumber based framework using jUnit

I have tried

```
Actions obj = new Actions(driver);
obj.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, "m"));
obj.build().perform();
```

Actions obj = new Actions(driver);
obj.sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT, "m");

I am using macbook pro m2 chip, java version = 17

my pom.xml file is:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont see the element where you perform the action to (target). You still need to specify the element I believe.

```
 WebElement clickable = driver.findElement(By.id("clickable"));
        new Actions(driver)
                .moveToElement(clickable)
                .sendKeys("abc")
                .perform();
```

Comment: Actually on a page i just want to click shift +m no element is there where i want to click

Comment: Try with the above suggestion.

Comment: You can use something like //body for the xpath locator

Comment: But what to locate there?

Comment: Its like suppose you are on one webpage and you click control+t then new tabs open so instead of Control+t i am clicking SHIFT + M, so for new tab also there is no xpath locator